# Height of watermark in Reporting Services 2008 R2

Tags: reporting-services

I want to embed a watermark into RS 2008 R2.

I tryied in a first time with an height of 1000 px but the bottom of the page is missing. With 800 px it is also the case. Does someone know what is the good height for a full sized A4 page ?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rs 2008 R2 has a resolution of 96 dpi so the best resolution of the watermark is 794 * 1123 for 21cm x 29.7cm.

I had some big troubles with a watermark which required a 300 dpi. You can't do it by default with RS.

If you need this you will have to use Web Services. for example : [Has anyone figured out a way to render a Reporting Services report at a resolution greater than 96ppi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578087/has-anyone-figured-out-a-way-to-render-a-reporting-services-report-at-a-resoluti)